# Sound Amplifier for Android

Tags: audio, volume-control, htc-wildfire-s

Is there any sound amplifier app for android? My HTC Wildfire S speaker is just too low for my ears even when at maximum. Is there any way I can boost the sounds? i.e Music Player, call ringtones e.t.c. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid this is not really an answer, but I found no way just to post a comment to the question so here it goes:

For the Samsung Galaxy S and the Samsung tablets, Vodoo control effectively amplifies the sound and it is available in the [Android Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.projectvoodoo.controlapp)

Comment: GT-S5660 - is not compatible saying.